# Problems with lbl reference in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

first time posting here, This code below should make a label in tkinter, and works that way in another program on mine, but doesnt in this other one, it gives the error shown in the attached picture. Would appreciate any help. thanks.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe8kT.png)

```
lblReference = Label(f1, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), 
            text = "Choose:", bd = 16, anchor = "w")
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. Instead, take the time to cut, paste, and format the message. Also, please post a [mcve] that replicates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your indentation you don’t have enough code here for us to see where it’s gone wrong I’m assuming somewhere further up in your code you just have to fix the indentation